# Anisotropic diffusion 2d images

Tags: python, c, image, matlab, filtering

I want to use anisotropic diffusion on 2d images.
I'd like to use python but don't mind using matlab or c. 
Are their any libraries I could use as a first step? I did a google search on the subject and found Panda3D and OpenGl.
Basically I want to give a set of images have it apply the filtering and then output the new image to a folder I want. 
Any tips on how to use either of these or maybe something that you believe is better?

edit: Meant diffusion sorry!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**[Here's](http://pastebin.com/sBsPX4Y7)** my Python/numpy implementation of 2D and 3D anisotropic (Perona-Malik) diffusion. It's not quite as fast as C-code, but it did the job nicely for me.

Comment: Wow thank you very much! Sorry for the delay, just saw this and it has been very helpfull!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Mark my answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: Don't have that much rep yet! Once I have enough I will for sure!

Comment: Actually Perona Malik is Isotropic (Non Linear) Diffusion.

Comment: @ali_m, Did you apply the Div operator twice as it should be?

Comment: @Drazick I called it "anisotropic" because most people (including Perona & Malik) call it that. It's a long time since I wrote that piece of code, but my recollection is that you only really need to compute the div once per image dimension, since subtracting a copy of the image shifted one pixel downwards will give you the same absolute difference as subtracting a copy shifted one pixel upwards. It's possible that I've made a mistake, though. You could check [Peter Kovesi's original MATLAB function](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/Spatial/anisodiff.m) if you want to be sure.

Comment: I'm looking at his code and again, it seems to me you only calculate the derivative once (While the Diffusion Equation of Perona Malik is the Divergence of the Gradient, namely 2 derivatives.

Comment: To be totally honest, I just ported this code from Kovesi's MATLAB version without rigorously following the formal definition of P-M diffusion. It's possible that his version is totally wrong as well, but I think it's unlikely, since he really knows his stuff. Having skimmed [the original paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/MP-aniso.pdf) again, I think equation 7 explains what's going on. We are in fact computing a discrete approximation of the Laplacian, using 1) the nearest-neighbor differences and 2) the conduction gradients (also a function of the nearest-neighbor differences).

Answer (score 7):

Anisotropic diffusion is available in the [`medpy` package](http://pythonhosted.org/MedPy/generated/medpy.filter.smoothing.anisotropic_diffusion.html) since 2013

```
import numpy as np
from medpy.filter.smoothing import anisotropic_diffusion

img = np.random.uniform(size=(32,32))
img_filtered = anisotropic_diffusion(img)
```

Comment: medpy seems to support Python 3 now. Git project page even says Python 2 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
try:
    from cv2 import cv2
except:
    import cv2
import numpy as np


class anisodiff2D(object):

    def __init__(self,num_iter=5,delta_t=1/7,kappa=30,option=2):

        super(anisodiff2D,self).__init__()

        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.delta_t = delta_t
        self.kappa = kappa
        self.option = option

        self.hN = np.array([[0,1,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,0]])
        self.hS = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,1,0]])
        self.hE = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,-1,1],[0,0,0]])
        self.hW = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,-1,0],[0,0,0]])
        self.hNE = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,-1,0],[0,0,0]])
        self.hSE = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,1]])
        self.hSW = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,-1,0],[1,0,0]])
        self.hNW = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,0]])

    def fit(self,img):

        diff_im = img.copy()

        dx=1; dy=1; dd = math.sqrt(2)

        for i in range(self.num_iter):

            nablaN = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hN)
            nablaS = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hS)
            nablaW = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hW)
            nablaE = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hE)
            nablaNE = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hNE)
            nablaSE = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hSE)
            nablaSW = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hSW)
            nablaNW = cv2.filter2D(diff_im,-1,self.hNW)

            cN = 0; cS = 0; cW = 0; cE = 0; cNE = 0; cSE = 0; cSW = 0; cNW = 0

            if self.option == 1:
                cN = np.exp(-(nablaN/self.kappa)**2)
                cS = np.exp(-(nablaS/self.kappa)**2)
                cW = np.exp(-(nablaW/self.kappa)**2)
                cE = np.exp(-(nablaE/self.kappa)**2)
                cNE = np.exp(-(nablaNE/self.kappa)**2)
                cSE = np.exp(-(nablaSE/self.kappa)**2)
                cSW = np.exp(-(nablaSW/self.kappa)**2)
                cNW = np.exp(-(nablaNW/self.kappa)**2)
            elif self.option == 2:
                cN = 1/(1+(nablaN/self.kappa)**2)
                cS = 1/(1+(nablaS/self.kappa)**2)
                cW = 1/(1+(nablaW/self.kappa)**2)
                cE = 1/(1+(nablaE/self.kappa)**2)
                cNE = 1/(1+(nablaNE/self.kappa)**2)
                cSE = 1/(1+(nablaSE/self.kappa)**2)
                cSW = 1/(1+(nablaSW/self.kappa)**2)
                cNW = 1/(1+(nablaNW/self.kappa)**2)

            diff_im = diff_im + self.delta_t * (

                (1/dy**2)*cN*nablaN +
                (1/dy**2)*cS*nablaS +
                (1/dx**2)*cW*nablaW +
                (1/dx**2)*cE*nablaE +

                (1/dd**2)*cNE*nablaNE +
                (1/dd**2)*cSE*nablaSE +
                (1/dd**2)*cSW*nablaSW +
                (1/dd**2)*cNW*nablaNW
            )

        return diff_im
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean [Anisotropic diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion)? C is probably the best(faster then matlab and python). But there is a toolbox for image analysis in matlab: [matlabimagetoolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/products/image/). 
I made a program for doing isotropic diffusion in c, the only lib I used was [libjpeg](http://ijg.org/) for importing and exporting the images.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry my bad. I meant Diffusion!
I'm very interested in how you did it in c.
How should i go into making it?

Comment: No not for homework, but for a project at uni. They need someone to create one, and I want to learn by creating it. I just heard of Anisotropic today so I'm trying to research it pretty well. Thank you for the information, I'm not very advance in C but I'll see what I can do. I'll see if I can find out anything on parsing images to float etc.

Comment: the image data is (if grayscale) in one unsigned char array. to parse,  float_image =(float)char_image_data. if u need more help I can post some code.