# Image goes black after thresholding

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to extract blood network from this face image: [Face image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/gic0vj8ujlp85fy/02_giorgos_1_f_M_30_830.tif/file)

For such task, i am using the P&M anisotropic diffusion found in this question: [Anisotropic diffusion 2d images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802611/anisotropic-diffusion-2d-images). Then i am using tophat transform followed by blackhat transform, afterwards i use a simple threshold to set to 255 all pixel that has an intensity value of 100.

The problem is that, after i use the threshold and try to open the image, whatever way i try, the image is displayed as fully black:

[image]

In short, my goal is to extract the blood vessels using P&M anisotropic diffusion with structuring element of flat disk of 5x5, then apply tophat and blackhat, respectively and a simple threshold and actually be able to view the image afterwards.

Here's my code on how i am trying it:

```
    import cv2 
    import import cv2 numpy as np
    import warnings

    face_img=mpimg.imread('path')
    def anisodiff(img, niter=1, kappa=50, gamma=0.1, step=(1., 1.), option=1):
        if img.ndim == 3:
            m = "Only grayscale images allowed, converting to 2D matrix"
            warnings.warn(m)
            img = img.mean(2)
    
        img = img.astype('float32')
        imgout = img.copy()
    
        deltaS = np.zeros_like(imgout)
        deltaE = deltaS.copy()
        NS = deltaS.copy()
        EW = deltaS.copy()
        gS = np.ones_like(imgout)
        gE = gS.copy()
    
        for ii in range(niter):
    
            deltaS[:-1, :] = np.diff(imgout, axis=0)
            deltaE[:, :-1] = np.diff(imgout, axis=1)
    
            if option == 1:
                    gS = np.exp(-(deltaS/kappa)**2.)/step[0]
                    gE = np.exp(-(deltaE/kappa)**2.)/step[1]
            elif option == 2:
                    gS = 1./(1.+(deltaS/kappa)**2.)/step[0]
                    gE = 1./(1.+(deltaE/kappa)**2.)/step[1]
    
            E = gE*deltaE
            S = gS*deltaS
    
            NS[:] = S
            EW[:] = E
            NS[1:, :] -= S[:-1, :]
            EW[:, 1:] -= E[:, :-1]
    
            imgout += gamma*(NS+EW)
    
        return imgout

new_img = anisodiff(face_img, niter=1, kappa=20, gamma=0.1, step=(1., 1.), option=1)

filterSize =(3, 3) 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,  
                                   filterSize) 
input_image = new_img 
first_tophat_img = cv2.morphologyEx(input_image,  
                              cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, 
                              kernel)
filterSize =(3, 3) 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, 
                                   filterSize) 
  
second_tophat_img = cv2.morphologyEx(input_image,  
                              cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, 
                              kernel) 

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(second_tophat_img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Even when i set the threshold to 254 for instance, the image goes black.

Comment: Does the image `second_tophat_img` show normally? You might need to **lower** the threshold, rather than increase it, to get some white pixels in the output.

Comment: It shows face countours alongside some edges around the face region, the background isn't getting removed unfortunately and finally when i do the thresholding for the value of 1, very little of the image is left, which isn't useful

Comment: @CrisLuengo i fixed it, sorry

Comment: So the method doesn't work, then. You might need to look for a different method. To be honest, I don't see any vessels in that face image, and it has quite a lot of imaging artefacts. Maybe you need to start by improving the imaging.

Comment: By the way, the anisotropic diffusion output is a floating-point image. You should be able to use thresholds lower than 1 meaningfully.

Comment: When i reduce the number of iterations to something 5-10 it gets a lot better, just the background that wont go away

Comment: As @CrisLuengo said, the image doesn't show any blood vessels. No matter what filters you use, the best you can get out of this image is the face and body separated from the background.

Comment: Body? theres only a face image, not a body

Comment: By body, I meant the neck+shoulder region.

Comment: Whats a good way to remove those parts and the background?

Comment: If you zoom in on the image, you can see that the chin and neck regions have similar pixel values and are indistinguishable. Other regions (background, shoulder) can be [segmented](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-segmentation-using-pythons-scikit-image-module-533a61ecc980) out, but that is a different problem than the question posted here. You should either edit this question or post a new one.

Comment: Ok back to the question then. You're saying there isnt blood vessels, which is not valid, given that the paper is about blood vessels segmentation, and there actually is blood vessels but you cant see them, did you try my code? did you read the image correctly?

Comment: The image size is 160x128 pixels. Looks like the image was taken from the paper (pdf) and not from the original dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218591/discussion-between-nirmal-and-rckjns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed a simple MATLAB implementation, and got a nice result.

MATLAB code:

```
I = imread('02_giorgos_1_f_M_30_830.tif');
I = im2double(uint8(I));

J = imdiffusefilt(I);
K = imtophat(J, ones(3));

figure;imshow(imadjust(K, stretchlim(K)));
```

Result:
[image]

I don't know if you know MATLAB, but I used the default arguments of `imdiffusefilt` (equivalent to `anisodiff` in your code).

Default MATLAB arguments are equivalent to:

- Input image is in range [0, 1] and not [0, 255].
- `niter=5` (note: you used only 1 iteration and it's not enough).
- `kappa=0.1`
- `gamma=0.125`
- MATLAB default is 8 neighbors connectivity (not 4 neighbors as used in `anisodiff`).

8 neighbors connectivity:

- For getting same result as in MATLAB, I implemented an 8 neighbors connectivity Anisotropic diffusion (based on MATLAB source code).
  Note: with 4 neighbors connectivity it's working, but result is not so nice as using 8 neighbors.

Displaying the output image:

- In order to display the output image correctly, I used `imadjust(K, stretchlim(K))`.
  The command stretches the range of the input image such that percentile 1 goes to 0, and percentile 99 goes to 1 (linear stretch).

One more thing:

- Instead of using fixed threshold of `200`, I used percentile 95 threshold:

  ```
   t = np.percentile(first_tophat_img, 95)
   ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(first_tophat_img, t, 255, 
   cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  ```

---

Here is the code (uses `cv2.imshow` for testing):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import warnings

face_img = mpimg.imread('02_giorgos_1_f_M_30_830.tif')

def anisodiff8neighbors(img, niter=5, kappa=0.1, gamma=0.125):
    """ See https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdiffusefilt.html 
        Anisotropic diffusion filtering with 8 neighbors
        Range of img is assumed to be [0, 1] (not [0, 255]).
    """
    if img.ndim == 3:
        m = "Only grayscale images allowed, converting to 2D matrix"
        warnings.warn(m)
        img = img.mean(2)
    
    img = img.astype('float32')
    imgout = img.copy()
    
   
    for ii in range(niter):
        # MATLAB source code is commented
        #paddedImg = padarray(I, [1 1], 'replicate');
        padded_img = np.pad(imgout, (1, 1), 'edge')

        #diffImgNorth = paddedImg(1:end-1,2:end-1) - paddedImg(2:end,2:end-1);
        #diffImgEast = paddedImg(2:end-1,2:end) - paddedImg(2:end-1,1:end-1);
        #diffImgNorthWest = paddedImg(1:end-2,1:end-2) - I;
        #diffImgNorthEast = paddedImg(1:end-2,3:end) - I;
        #diffImgSouthWest = paddedImg(3:end,1:end-2) - I;
        #diffImgSouthEast = paddedImg(3:end,3:end) - I;
        diff_img_north = padded_img[0:-1, 1:-1] - padded_img[1:, 1:-1]
        diff_img_east = padded_img[1:-1, 1:] - padded_img[1:-1, 0:-1]
        diff_img_north_west = padded_img[0:-2, 0:-2] - imgout
        diff_img_north_east = padded_img[0:-2, 2:] - imgout
        diff_img_south_west = padded_img[2:, 0:-2] - imgout
        diff_img_south_east = padded_img[2:, 2:] - imgout

        #case 'exponential'
        #conductCoeffNorth = exp(-(abs(diffImgNorth)/gradientThreshold).^2);
        #conductCoeffEast = exp(-(abs(diffImgEast)/gradientThreshold).^2);
        #conductCoeffNorthWest = exp(-(abs(diffImgNorthWest)/gradientThreshold).^2);
        #conductCoeffNorthEast = exp(-(abs(diffImgNorthEast)/gradientThreshold).^2);
        #conductCoeffSouthWest = exp(-(abs(diffImgSouthWest)/gradientThreshold).^2);
        #conductCoeffSouthEast = exp(-(abs(diffImgSouthEast)/gradientThreshold).^2);
        conduct_coeff_north = np.exp(-(np.abs(diff_img_north)/kappa)**2.0)
        conduct_coeff_east = np.exp(-(np.abs(diff_img_east)/kappa)**2.0)
        conduct_coeff_north_west = np.exp(-(np.abs(diff_img_north_west)/kappa)**2.0)
        conduct_coeff_north_east = np.exp(-(np.abs(diff_img_north_east)/kappa)**2.0)
        conduct_coeff_south_west = np.exp(-(np.abs(diff_img_south_west)/kappa)**2.0)
        conduct_coeff_south_east = np.exp(-(np.abs(diff_img_south_east)/kappa)**2.0)
        
        #fluxNorth = conductCoeffNorth .* diffImgNorth;
        #fluxEast =  conductCoeffEast .* diffImgEast;
        #fluxNorthWest = conductCoeffNorthWest .* diffImgNorthWest;
        #fluxNorthEast = conductCoeffNorthEast .* diffImgNorthEast;
        #fluxSouthWest = conductCoeffSouthWest .* diffImgSouthWest;
        #fluxSouthEast = conductCoeffSouthEast .* diffImgSouthEast;
        flux_north = conduct_coeff_north * diff_img_north
        flux_east = conduct_coeff_east * diff_img_east
        flux_north_west = conduct_coeff_north_west * diff_img_north_west
        flux_north_east = conduct_coeff_north_east * diff_img_north_east
        flux_south_west = conduct_coeff_south_west * diff_img_south_west
        flux_south_east = conduct_coeff_south_east * diff_img_south_east

        #% Discrete PDE solution
        #I = I + diffusionRate * (fluxNorth(1:end-1,:) - fluxNorth(2:end,:) + ...
        #    fluxEast(:,2:end) - fluxEast(:,1:end-1) + (1/(dd^2)).* fluxNorthWest + ...
        #    (1/(dd^2)).* fluxNorthEast + (1/(dd^2)).* fluxSouthWest + (1/(dd^2)).* fluxSouthEast);
        imgout = imgout + gamma * (flux_north[0:-1,:] - flux_north[1:,:] + 
            flux_east[:,1:] - flux_east[:,0:-1] + 0.5*flux_north_west + 
            0.5*flux_north_east + 0.5*flux_south_west + 0.5*flux_south_east)
    
    return imgout


#new_img = anisodiff(face_img, niter=1, kappa=20, gamma=0.1, step=(1., 1.), option=1)
face_img = face_img.astype(float) / 255;
#new_img = anisodiff(face_img, niter=5, kappa=0.1, gamma=0.125, step=(1., 1.), option=1)
new_img = anisodiff8neighbors(face_img, niter=5, kappa=0.1, gamma=0.125)

filterSize =(3, 3) 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,  
                                   filterSize) 
input_image = new_img 
first_tophat_img = cv2.morphologyEx(input_image,
                              cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, 
                              kernel)

# Use percentile 95 (of image) as threshold instead of fixed threshold 200
t = np.percentile(first_tophat_img, 95)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(first_tophat_img, t, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh1)


filterSize =(3, 3) 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, 
                                   filterSize) 
  

second_tophat_img = cv2.morphologyEx(input_image,  
                              cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, 
                              kernel) 


#ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(second_tophat_img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Use percentile 95 (of image) as threshold instead of fixed threshold 200
t = np.percentile(second_tophat_img, 95)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(second_tophat_img, t, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('thresh2', thresh2)

lo, hi = np.percentile(first_tophat_img, (1, 99))
first_tophat_img_stretched = (first_tophat_img.astype(float) - lo) / (hi-lo) # Apply linear "stretch" - lo goes to 0, and hi goes to 1
cv2.imshow('first_tophat_img_stretched', first_tophat_img_stretched)


cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

`thresh1`:
[image]

`thresh2`:
[image]

`first_tophat_img_stretched`:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, my code produces the same result, i came to the conclusion that, if you're achieving the same results with different parameters, thats the actual blood vessel, right?

Comment: I have no idea if these are actual blood vessels (or parts that gets warmer due to blood vessels). The paper refers them as "blood vessels". These are "blood vessels" in the context of your post.